# Best hybrid for GUI programming in python

Tags: java, python, jython

Which would be the most recommended python hybrid to create GUI application?
I have tested out jython which was really easy, i also like that java is practically on every OS ever so porting my application to other OS's will be easy.

What do you programmers recommend?

Comment: "python hybrid"? What's that? Jython is a Python implementation.

Comment: Portability is not a language implementation property (any more). In most modern languages, all programs can be run on a myrad of systems, including some neither of us has never heard of and all we'll ever care about. Of course many won't work because the program itself is not portable - because its author(s) broke portability by making stupid assumptions about how parts of the system work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I prefer [PySide](http://www.pyside.org/), based on Qt4 which runs on most platforms.

There's a huge list [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GuiProgramming) about different frameworks.

Comment: With PySide, can you create mobile applications? Thanks for that list btw

Comment: Mainly Maemo5 so far and being ported to S60, however it should be semi-easy to port to android.

Answer (score 1):

If you're mainly targeting Windows, nothing beats the power and flexibility of [IronPython](http://ironpython.net), in my opinion.

As a fully featured .NET language, you can easily write powerful apps using WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation), and as a bonus, interface with any library, class or module anyone ever wrote in any .NET language. Having access to the entire world of .NET assemblies out there and getting to write in python while doing it personally rocks my proverbial socks.

Comment: Not trying to be rude, but why use a framework that limits you to 1 platform then use something like pything? might as well write the code in C# or something.

Comment: [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page) is available for Linux and Mac OSX. And this question is about python-supporting GUI frameworks; thanks to IronPython, WPF now qualifies for that title.

Answer (score 0):

I like [codeskulptor.org](http://www.codeskulptor.org).

It is easy for beginners, but for the one who has experience and high requirements, it is maybe useless.